# Attach Snapshot Debugger option not available in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-application-insights

Trying to enable snapshot debugging on an Azure app service. The option to enable the snapshot debugger is not showing up in Visual Studio 2017. Did install the Snapshot Debugger Extension. Upgraded the Insights SDK on the deployed app service to the latest version (2.4.1).

The Visual Studio version I use is VS 2017 Enterprise 15.5.2.

Is this because snapshot debugging is only available for sites? Early blog posts about this feature seem to suggest this, but I'm not sure this is still the case.

The app service I try to snapshot debug is a Web API (.NET framework version 4.6.1).

Any suggestions about steps I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ASP.NET API apps are not currently covered.

The Snapshot Debugger was made available in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise version 15.5 and greater. VS2017 supported ASP.NET (4.6.1+) and ASP.NET Core (2.0+) running in Azure App Services, however, it currently covers Web UI scenarios.

[FYI: VS2019 supports several more Azure scenarios (VM,VMSS,AKS)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2019/01/29/debug-your-live-apps-running-in-azure-virtual-machines-and-azure-kubernetes/).